# Controller usage get crash on Phalcon 2.0.9

Tags: php, phalcon, phalcon-routing

So now, I code on my project using micro phalcon. It seems work without using controllers. By the time my code get bigger and bigger for increasing number of API routes. I put all of my codes in app.php. Is there any chance of me to get better looking of code block without losing performance? I've tried adding controller to use like tutorial in https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/micro.html#using-controllers-as-handlers but seems I can't do that. I always get error if I use MicroCollection. I need request->getRawJSON, modelsManager, and a Request funtion. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We don't support 1.x branch for a long time. Try 2.x please

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm typo about that. Actually, I use 2.0.9 phalcon